# Why do i get null after using the foreach method in Flutter wih Firestore?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, async-await, stream

I was trying to get a user document and its sub-collection, simultaneously. But I found that it is not possible within a query. So I have decided to approach the problem from another perspective.

---

## What do we have?

I have a `getRelative()` getter and it returns `Stream<Relative>`.

```js
  Stream<Relative> get getRelative async* {
    List<Patient> patientList;

    patientList = await getPatientCollection
        .forEach((element) => element.patients)
        .then((value) => value);

      yield* usersCollection
          .document(_userEmail)
          .snapshots()
          .map((snapshot) => _relativeDataFromSnapshot(snapshot, patientList));
    
  }
```

`getPatientCollection()` is another getter method and it returns `Stream<PatinetList>`. I am not gonna give detail of the getter. Because it works fine.

---

## What is the problem?

The problem is when I get `Stream<PatientList>`, I am getting a `Stream`. So, just to convert it to `Future`, I have used `forEach` method. And it also works fine. I can see `element.patients` is not empty. I can see inside of it and its return type `List<Patient>` as it should be.

But when I was debugging it, after `forEach()` has done its job, I have realized that it return null. And `patientList` become null. That causes a problem.

---

## What am I asking?

1. What does it cause this problem? And how can I solve it?
2. Is there any better way to get subcollection without using another Stream to get patient subcollection (`getPatientCollection`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Stream.forEach` is the `Stream` equivalent of `List.forEach` (which returns `void`).  It's for doing some operation on each element, not for returning a new collection.  If you want to convert a `Stream<T>` to a `List<T>`, you can do [`await stream.toList()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-async/Stream/toList.html).

Comment: You have just saved me James. I don't have any idea how I missed that. Thank you so much!